# Identityserver3: Token validation requests not visible in Fiddler

Tags: validation, fiddler, identityserver3, endpoint

In fiddler composer, I execute a call to a local api that is secured by a local identityserver3.

I added the token, and I configured the middleware to validate the token on the server. Tt works fine, in Idenityserver3 log file I see a succesful token validation logmessage for the configured scope.

I assume that, with htis config, each time the api is called, the Idsrv3 middleware calls the token validation endpoint under the hood.

My issue is that fiddler does not show this middleware request, just the call to the api itself. Is this due to fiddler settings or is there another reason this request is invisible to fiddler?

Is there a way to display it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could be that .NET is not routing the localhost traffic to fiddler proxy. For workaround check this. 
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost

Also, check if you have configured validation mode properly. According to documentation https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/identityTokenValidation.html validation endpoint is useful if you have no access to crypto libraries locally.

Valid validation modes are

1. `ValidationMode.Both` - Use local validation for JWTs and the validation endpoint for reference tokens
2. `ValidationMode.Local` - Use local validation oly (only suitable for JWT tokens)
3. `ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint` - Use the validation endpoint only (works for both JWT and reference tokens)

You can set the validation mode in `IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions`

```
            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
                    //RequiredScopes = new[] { "write" },

                    // client credentials for the introspection endpoint
                    ClientId = "write",
                    ClientSecret = "secret",
                    ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local
                });
```

Comment: I don't use localhost-refs, but hosts entries for all local sites. As a test I opened http://127.0.0.1/, which was captured by fiddler

Filters also don't seem an issue, clicking help>Troubleshoot does not show anything in strikethrough font.

I'm using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware, having problems with the human user in the implicit flow. The token is expired but the user stays authenticated. I I don't seem to be able to set validation mode here

Comment: If you are using webapi, you need to have start-up with `UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` middleware configured. `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` middleware is for MVC clients

Comment: Well I have both, using the UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication for issuing a backend ajax token in my MVC app, not sure if this is the right approach though

Comment: hmmm I see, all ajax requests to the backend get authorized through the cookie auth, I don't seem to need a backend token!

Comment: yeah. If your back end is not supposed to be called by external clients, then no need to use bearer authentication.